# What is the difference beetwen getLocation() and getLocationOnScreen() at JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

What is the difference beetwen `getLocation()` and `getLocationOnScreen()` metholds at `JFrame`?

I wanted to test what is the difference with this code, but the result is the same. Which method should I use?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocation(150, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("getLocation: " + frame.getLocation().getX() + " " + frame.getLocation().getY());
    System.out.println("getLocationOnScreen: " + frame.getLocationOnScreen().getX() + " " + frame.getLocationOnScreen().getY());
}
```

Output:

```
getLocation: 150.0 100.0

getLocationOnScreen: 150.0 100.0
```

Comment: These are methods of Component, and are thus not specific to JFrame. Their javadoc explain what they do. Read the javadoc: it's your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a JFrame like this, the parent is null, so it's the screen. That's why here, the functions returns the same values : `getLocationOnScreen()` returns the position of your frame relatively to your screen and `getLocation()` returns the position of your frame relatively to its parent, here, the screen